# Prove that: $\forall x \in V \space\space f(x)\ge0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume that $V$ is a vector space and $f:V\to \mathbb R$ is a function such that we have:
(i) $f(x+y) \le f(x)+f(y)$
(ii) $f(cx) = |c|f(x)$

> Prove that:  $\forall x \in V \space\space f(x)\ge0$

Note: The definition and the properties of $f$ seems too normal to me! I don't see a relevance between those two properties and the statement which the question wants us to prove.  Any hints? answers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In (ii) do you mean $f(cx) = |c| f(x)$?

Comment: @Gregory yes... excuse me for the mistake :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f(0) = f(0x) = 0f(x) = 0 $, using (ii) and so
$$ 0 = f(0) = f(x-x) \leq f(x) + f(-x) = 2f(x) $$
by (i) and then (ii) on the second term.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f(0)=0$ by $(ii)$. Hence $$0=f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x-1x)\leq f(x)+f(-1x)=f(x)+f(x)=2f(x).$$